# Spring Batch configuration for running multiple jobs

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing

I am trying to run multiple jobs for reading from several databases and write into our Db. We just have one job now which is working fine and we have transaction manager configured to that particular datasource.

Now, for running multiple jobs for reading from different Db's, how do we go about configuring job-launcher.xml as we now have multiple datasources? How would it know how these jobs should be executed and call the appropriate Transaction manager?

I am new to spring batch and would appreciate any help in this regards. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may wish to start by generalizing the flow of your job, taking advantage of job inheritance and parameters, as well as abstract references to beans within that flow that are specific to a particular job.